Proving that the point is fixed
Circle with the center O, and also points A and B on it are fixed on a plane, M is the midpoint of AB. Points P and Q are chosen arbitrarily on the circle, the tangent line through P intersects AB at point C, CQ intersects circle the second time at point D. The circle passing through points D, M, Q intersects AB the second time at point E. Prove that the intersection of PE and OM remains constant for any choice of points P and Q.
Here is the diagram (black points are fixed, blue ones are arbitrarily chosen, green depend on blue ones, and red point is the one in question)

This was the last question on my final exam, and the teacher herself didn't know how to solve it. I have only noticed that CPOM is cyclic, but this didn't lead to anything. I also tried to solve it in coordinates, and this probably would lead us to a solution, but there were so many variables and equations that I decided to stop because of the lack of time.

Welcome to MSE. What a nice exercice (and diagram ).

Note that if $P\in OM$, the tangent line through $P $ does not intersect $AB$.

Do you know $\mathbb C$?

Also, which exam? What was the level? What theorems do you know about radical axis and harmonic quadrilaterals?

If by $\mathbb C$ you mean involving complex numbers in geometry, then yes, i do. I know about properties of midpoints of diagonals in harmonic quadrilaterals, know properties of symmedian, humpty/dumpty points and so on. About radical axis, well, not too much - know that this is a line where all powers of the points are equal, and about the power center. This is the last exam in the 3rd quarter of last (11th) grade in the math lyceum (we have already finished 2d geometry course 2 yeras ago). Don't know if it will help, and thank you very much!

@Meison good. Then you will be able to understand my answer.

The circle passing through $D,M,Q$. Not "A circle...." Isn't it?

Do you know pole and polar ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar... I have a very elegant demonstration with poles and polars. If you don't know, it's an opportunity to learn. I could try to be didactic. :)

Wow! I don't know, but will be happy to learn!

This was not as easy as I thought.
Draw the second tangent (other than $CP$) from $C$ to the circle with centre $O$ and call it $CJ$. Define $E'$ as the intersection of $AB$ and $PJ$.

Claim: $E = E'$.
Proof: It suffices to show that $D,E',M,Q$ are concyclic. 
Note that $PBJA$ is a harmonic quadrilateral. It is well known that $M,P,C,J$ are concyclic. (As you've noticed, $O$ lies on this circle too.) Consider $\triangle CPE'$ and $\triangle CMP$. $\angle PCE' = \angle MCP$ and $\angle CPE' = \angle CPJ = \angle CMJ = \angle CMP$ (as $CP=CJ$). Hence $\triangle CPE' \sim \triangle CMP$. Particularly, $\overline{CE'} \cdot \overline{CM} = \overline{CP}^2$. But, $\overline{CP}^2 = \overline{CD} \cdot \overline{CQ}$, so that $\overline{CE'} \cdot \overline{CM} = \overline{CD} \cdot \overline{CQ} \iff D,E',M,Q \text{ are concyclic}$.

Now, since $PBJA$ is harmonic, the tangents from $A$ and $B$, and $PJ = PE$ must concur. It is not hard to see that they concur on $OM$.

Very beautiful. Not surprising I couldn't solve it. This is just one more proof the geometry is very hard.

Well it isn't hard naturally, but it was made to be hard by redefining $E$, and I had to spend a lot of time doing futile angle chasing to show the two definitions are equivalent.

Let $(O)$ be a circle.Each point $P$(other than $O$) corresponds to a line $p$, called the polar of $P$ with respect to $(O)$, which is perpendicular to $OP$. Conversely, every line $p$ (not passing through point $O$) corresponds to a point $P$, called the pole of $p$ with respect to $(O)$. We will now refer to $a,b,c,\varphi...$ the polars of points $A, B,C, \phi...$
It is immediate, and can be found in many geometry classes(example : Geometry revisited by Coxeter, th. 6.11)
$$\boxed{\text{If a passes through B, then b passes through A}}\color{red}{(*)}$$

We will demonstrate



$c=PE$




if $\varphi:=AB$ then $F=\phi$



with the notations in the figure belowhttps://www.geogebra.org/classic/jagkdwbp


By definition of the polar, we have to prove that $$\vec{MC}.\vec{ME}=\vec{MA}^2$$
We know that $$\vec{CA}.\vec{CB}=\vec{CD}.\vec{CQ} \text{( power of $C$ with respect to (O))}$$ $$\vec{CD}.\vec{CQ}=\vec{CE}.\vec{CM} \text{( power of $C$ with respect to (DMQ))}$$

So, $$\vec{CA}.\vec{CB}=\vec{CE}.\vec{CM}$$ $$\implies (\vec{CM}+\vec{MA}).(\vec{CM}+\vec{MB})=(\vec{CM}+\vec{ME}).\vec{CM}$$ $$\implies  \vec{MA}.\vec{MB}=\vec{ME}.\vec{CM}$$
So, $$c=PE$$

2.- According to $\color{red}{(*)}$, as $C$ belongs to $\varphi:=AB$, $$\phi \in c=PE$$
On the other hand, we know that $$\phi \in \text{ the perpendicular OM to }\varphi=AB \text{ passing through }O$$
Then $$F=\color{red}{\phi} \text{ pole of }\varphi:=AB.\square$$

Oh my, I was actually able to understand everything. This is a very beautiful solution, too!

Some people sometimes reproach me for being a very bad teacher. What you write here gives me great pleasure. Thank you :) I hope I haven't written nonsense; others more knowledgeable than me will point them out if that is the case.

@StéphaneJaouen I am often confused as to whether there is some advantage in using pole and polar over using inversions, can you elaborate?

@D S : I'm afraid I'm not qualified enough to do it, but Coxeter's book, Geometry Revisited, is an excellent reference I think.
